# Regular Expression in sed for multiple replacements in one statement

Tags: regex, sed, sublimetext2, regex-group

I want to sanitise some input and replace several characters with acceptable input, e.g. a Danish '`å`' with '`aa`'.

This is easily done using several statements, e.g. `/æ/ae/`, `/å/aa/`, `/ø/oe/`, but due to tool limitations, I want to be able to do this in a single regular expression.

I can catch all of the relevant cases (`/[(æ)(ø)(å)(Æ)(Ø)(Å)]/`) but I replacement does not work as I want it to (but probably completely as intended):

```
 $ temp="RødgrØd med flæsk"

 $ echo $temp
 RødgrØd med flæsk

 $ echo $temp | sed 's/[(æ)(ø)(å)(Æ)(Ø)(Å)]/(ae)(oe)(aa)(Ae)(Oe)(Aa)/g'
 R(ae)(oe)(aa)(Ae)(Oe)(Aa)dgr(ae)(oe)(aa)(Ae)(Oe)(Aa)d med fl(ae)(oe)(aa)(Ae)(Oe)(Aa)sk
```

(first echo line is to show that it isn't an encoding issue)

Just as an aside, the tool issue is that I should like to also use the same regex in a [Sublime Text 2 snippet](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10509).

Anyone able to discern what is wrong with my regex statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `sed` the only possibility? What about `awk`, `perl`, `ruby`, `raku`, etc.?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Split it up into several `sed` statements, separated by `;`:

```
sed 's/æ/ae/g;s/ø/oe/g;s/å/aa/g;s/Æ/Ae/g;s/Ø/Oe/g;s/Å/Aa/g'
```

Comment: Blarg, of course. I should have emphasized the Sublime Text snippet usage more, but this is the completely correct answer to the main question.

Comment: @Jan, thanks. I don't think you can write a single regex that replaces one of several possible matches with one of several replacements, especially not with `sed`.

Answer (score 11):

With

```
sed -e 's/Find/Replace/g;s/Find/Replace/g;[....];/Find/Replace/g'
```

you'll do the trick.

So, translate into what you need

```
sed -e 's/æ/ae/g;s/ø/oe/g;s/å/aa/g;s/Æ/Ae/g;s/Ø/Oe/g;s/Å/Aa/g'
```

Comment: Blarg, of course. I should have emphasized the Sublime Text snippet usage more, but this is the completely correct answer to the main question.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/$/\næaeøoeåaaÆAeØOeÅAa/;:a;s/([æøåÆØÅ])(.*\n.*\1(..))/\3\2/;ta;s/\n.*//' file
```

It works by adding a lookup table to the end of the line, looping until all keys are replaced then removes the lookup table.